# Apache htaccess: rewrite directory to query param

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know there are quite some questions out there about this issue but I have not yet been able to find the exact way how to do a rewrite in my case:

Having an application available at `https://example.com/dev/myapp/#/?query=1234`, I would like to allow an alternative access using this URL: `https://example.com/dev/myapp/1234` without creating a sub-directory /1234.

Using the htaccess, I would like that the latter URL is rewritten/ forwarded to the former URL.

What I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myapp/([^/])?$ myapp/index.html?query=$1 [L]
```

will forward

```
https://example.com/dev/myapp/1234
```

to

```
https://example.com/dev/myapp/1234#/
```

And

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!myapp/)([^/])?$ /dev/myapp?query=$1 [L,R=302]
```

will forward

```
https://example.com/dev/myapp/1234
```

to

```
https://example.com/dev/myapp/?query=1234#/
```

I am somehow stuck with getting the syntax right. Any help?

Comment: "allow an alternative access using this URL: `https://example.com/dev/myapp/1234`" - Are you wanting to keep that URL in the browser's address bar, or simply redirect the request back to the URL your application currently understands? (Which I assume is being processed by client-side JS?)

Comment: @anubhava Yes, `myapp` is a real subdirectory. .htaccess could be inside both, myapp or the parent directory, preferably inside `myapp` though.

Comment: @MrWhite That's a good question. It could be that 'keeping that URL in the address bar' would be neccessary. But to be honest I would need to test, if both result in the same behaviour since the issue is to install the PWA app on the mobile and it will in some cases omit/ not understand the query param.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understood, I create regex with group contain the numbers and re-used it for your query parameter, with NE flag for "noescape" output and keep "#" syntax, the [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

A. You can use in your virtualhost, the code below, the url will changed.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/dev/myapp/([0-9]+)$ /dev/myapp/\#/?query=$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

B. If you need to keep url of source, enable in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module       modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module  modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

And you can use in your virtualhost, the code below. (P for proxy)

```
  SSLProxyEngine on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/dev/myapp/([0-9]+)$ /dev/myapp/\#/?query=$1 [P]
```

I hope that will help you

Comment: thanks for the answer! Both versions do not yet work for me. On which level do I have to put it into the .htaccess, `https://example.com/`, `https://example.com/dev/` or `https://example.com/dev/myapp/`? I would prefer, if I could put it inside `https://example.com/dev/` or `https://example.com/dev/myapp/`, but right now, I get a 404 error.

Comment: Hello,
You need to set it at the root domain like https://example.com/
I hope that will help you